# POSTMAN how to add authorization header in rest call

Tags: rest, postman

Hi I am trying to do a post call via POSTMAN and I want to understand how can I add authorization header.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can try below steps to add authorization header.

[image: Click Authorization tab]

Add body headers

[image: Body HEaders]

Add raw body

[image: Body content]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for more clarity. Let me try this.

Comment: Seems to be working I got some response from the api finally

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You might have to click on the authorization tab. that's it i guess